# PHP classes totally forgotten something today - sorry

Tags: php, class, opensocial

really sorry about being "totally thick today" but I have forgotten how to do something simple - too much time not in php recently.

Want to use the OS phpapi 
How do I print out the individual rows - see told you I was being thick today

```
 // The fields we will be fetching.


 if (isset($_GET['test']) && $_GET['test'] == 'plaxo') {
    // plaxo is a PortableContacts end-point so doesn't know about the OpenSocial specific fields
    $profile_fields = array();
  } else {
    $profile_fields = array(
        'aboutMe',
        'displayName',
        'bodyType',
        'currentLocation',
        'drinker',
        'happiestWhen',
        'lookingFor'
    );
  }
```

// The number of friends to fetch.

```
  $friend_count = 2;

$batch = $osapi->newBatch();
    // Fetch the current user.
      $self_request_params = array(
          'userId' => $userId,              // Person we are fetching.
          'groupId' => '@self',             // @self for one person.
          'fields' => $profile_fields       // Which profile fields to request.
      );
  $batch->add($osapi->people->get($self_request_params), 'self');

  // Fetch the friends of the user
  $friends_request_params = array(
      'userId' => $userId,              // Person whose friends we are fetching.
      'groupId' => '@friends',          // @friends for the Friends group.
      'fields' => $profile_fields,      // Which profile fields to request.
      'count' => $friend_count          // Max friends to fetch.
  );
  $batch->add($osapi->people->get($friends_request_params), 'friends');

  // Get supportedFields Request
  $batch->add($osapi->people->getSupportedFields(), 'supportedFields');

  // Send the batch request.
  $result = $batch->execute();
```

Say I wanted to print out "aboutMe",  whats the echo? cos echo $result['aboutMe'] doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know the product in question, but you may be able to find out by doing a ´print_r($result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am far from a php expert and admittedly know nothing about the specific product you are using I find that using [`var_dump($result)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) helps a lot with debugging.